# Inserting model(object) into table

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question regarding to codeigniter database class

according to user guide, I can easily insert a new row (or in other word, object) into my table by using

```
$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'name' => $name,
               'date' => $date
            );
```

However, is this possible for me to take a class (or model) that has title, name, date attribute (and possibly getter and setters for those attribute)
and pass in a new object of that model class into $this->db->insert('user', $model);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeignier's Active record doesn't support sending Model's object to insert function, but you can use ORM library like [Ignited Records](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/IgnitedRecord/wiki) or [DataMapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)  if you want to use object orientation technoque for database operation

as per [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) you can send object of a class like this

```
 class Myclass {
     var $title = 'My Title';
     var $content = 'My Content';
     var $date = 'My Date';
 }

$object = new Myclass;    
$this->db->insert('mytable', $object);
```

Comment: It kinda sucks to hear that Codeigniter doesn't support this feature, which would have become helpful for developers.